# What server does this response header return? nginx or apache?

Tags: apache, nginx, server

What server does this response header return? nginx or apache ?

```
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, No-Cache, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Verification-Hash, User-Id, User-Token
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-max-age: 36000
cache-control: max-age=0
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 03 Jul 2019 12:15:06 GMT
expires: Wed, 03 Jul 2019 12:15:06 GMT
server: jfe
status: 200
```

Comment: What makes you think that it's either nginx or apache?

Comment: Try using nmap !